# How to get the files that are added using "git add .", failed "git commit" due to typo and git pull from remote

Tags: git, github

I have lost major changes I have made. I list out the series of git commands I used.

1. git add .
2. git commit -mm "message" {this failed I guess due to -mm but I didnt see anything on console}
3. git pull origin master {to get changes from master}
   This showed I have changes on bundle.js an dbundle.map.js. So I deleted them. 
   I did a "git stash".
   But by now I noticed all other files were modified with contents on remote repo {as I did git pull origin master}

I tried looking lost-found but I could not see the blob which has my changes. Is it possible to retrieve the lost content? How can I retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command you did, i notice the usage of `git stash`. Git stash will move the changes you made away from the current working directory.

You can view the last stashed content by:

```
git stash show
```

and see if your changes is there.

If it does, do a

```
git stash apply
```

For deleted bundle.js. I don't see a way to retrieve changed the file. You can check trash (or something similar in your os).

However, you can always get the last committed state on bundle.js by checking out from the HEAD

```
git checkout bundle.js
```

**Side note**

I have seen a good Git Gui that can help you easily browse stashed changes and check out from there. The software is Git Eye. However, it is been several years I haven't use Git Eye as now. I'm getting more comfortable with command line.

Comment: I had tried for git stash appy. But there was error. error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        public/bundle.js
        public/bundle.js.map
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting. I'm don't know how to go about from here.

Comment: That means you have changed your files since then, so just commit that and then git stash apply.

Comment: @user2528718 Yes checking out from stash can be messy, I dont recommend commiting current changes just to get stashed changes. There is a more complicated way to do that (probably have been explained in other SO question + answer). I added side note to try out git eye, for easier management of stashed content :). Anyway, if your answer is working, then it is work.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Yana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3034747/yana)

The sequence of steps I used are

- git stash show {showed all files being stashed}
- git stash show -p {made sure all the changes are there}
- Created a new branch and saved the stashed content to new branch.
- git add . & git commit -m "updated one" {as I had bundle.js modified}
- git stash pop